# Javascript intermittently executing in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, flexslider

On [this page](http://olsta.brightagency.net), my javascript file only intermittently executes. There is an alert call in the file to make it obvious when it's executing. The contents of the file in question are below.

As far as I can tell, this is only happening in Internet Explorer 9.

What can I do to determine why it is not always executing?

Code in question:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.flexslider').length) {
        console.log($('.flexslider').length);
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            controlNav: false,
            animation: "slide",
        });
        alert('sucess');
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your code here, don't just link to it.

Comment: It works every time on IE 9 for me...

Comment: Are you doing any AJAX to load content?

Comment: @Ian no AJAX loading of content. Adrian Ber had the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with console.log. In IE if you don't have the Developer Tools window open, console is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, that makes an awful lot of sense now.

Comment: That's not logic, but that's IE :).